# How to organize objects in a tile-based game

Tags: algorithm, tiles, data-structure

I'm currently developing a tile-based RPG from scratch using C++ and SFML2.

So far, I got the map rendering and collision detection working just fine and in a clean, maintainable way. The next step is to implement objects on the map with which the player can interact and it feels like this is a bigger problem than it should be.

Here is an example what I want to do: Let's say there is a switch object, that has the property if it is on or off. Additionally there is a door object that has the property if it is open or closed and a list of switches. The controller will now iterate through all objects, if it is a Door, check all the switches assigned to it and if all of them are on, open the door.

My first, naive approach would look like this:

```
class GameObject
{
   //some common attributes
}

class Switch: GameObject
{
   bool isOn;
};

class Door: GameObject
{
   bool isOpen;
   vector<Switch> switches;
};
```

The problem is that different objects have different attributes and using inheritance would cause a ton of classes and I had to implement a new class every time I want to introduce a new object. Additionally to the clutter that causes, it would also not be very efficient as the controller had always look up the concrete type of the object it is iterating over and casting it to that type. Constantly having to look up the derived types of a type is also a sign of bad design.

Is there a better way to organize the objects than using classes and inheritance? I looked up the Entity-Component-System Pattern which looks like it's addressing this problem but it feels like an overkill for what I want to do. Also ECS don't fit in with my current architecture and seems in general not very suitable to be used in a tile-based game.

I'd really appreciate any ideas or hints! Thanks a lot in advance!

**Edit:**

To clarify, here are my issues I have with ECS and tile maps: I currently organized the data of the map like this:

```
map<Coordinate,Tile> mapData
```

This is pretty efficient when it comes to collision detection. So with an ECS, I have following options:

- I could create a tile entity with coordinates and tiletype as components. That would make collision detection very inefficent. I'll have to iterate over every entity to look up if there is even a tile at the given position.
- I could have an entity that holds the whole tile map in a tile map component but that would be a misuse of components as far as I understood the concept.
- Using the tile map as an external, non-entity object and inject it to systems that needs it. That's kind of the opposite of what I want to achieve. I want to have a list of dynamic entities to be used on a map and end up building everything around entities, and build exceptions into the architecture.

Comment: It sounds like you've found the present game industry standard approach to this problem, ie. component-based architectures. Note that not every component-based approach needs to be a strictly data-oriented ECS: you can pick from it the ideas that work for you, without investing in more engineering than is beneficial for your use case.

Comment: Thanks! Well I was thinking about using ECS for the objects only and keep using the OOP approach for the tilemap and collision detection itself. However looking into ECS, it looks like mixing stuff up will clutter the whole architecture. Like for example parts of the tile renderer have to work on the Entities, and part on the objects of the tilemap

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain why you think components would not work for your map, when other game engines like Unity are able to use components together with tile maps effectively? The better we can understand this perceived blocker, the better we can help you overcome it. "Seems" doesn't tell us what concrete problem we need to solve.

Comment: There's no rule in a component-based solution that you can't keep using the map approach that you like. Don't worry about "misuse of components" - there are no component police who will arrest you for making a component implementation that works for you.